# I am getting this error message. Run Time error '1004' Method 'Range' of object'_Global' Failed

Tags: vba, excel, error-handling

I am trying to copy text values only from column H and move them to E. I want to automate it so that everytime a text value comes to H from sheet1, it directly goes to E instead of H. Leaving H empty in that cell.

```
    Sheets("102Tk").Select
    Dim row As Long
    For row = 17 To 1000
        ' Check if "textvalue" appears in the value anywhere.
        If WorksheetFunction.IsText(Range("H" & i)) Then
            ' Copy the value and then blank the source.
            Range("E" & i).value = Range("H" & i).value
            Range("H" & i).value = ""
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: You didn't declare `i`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Should i be row?

```
Option Explicit
Sub n()

    Sheets("102Tk").Select 
    Dim row As Long

    For row = 17 To 1000
        ' Check if "save" appears in the value anywhere.
        If Not IsNumeric(Range("H" & row)) Then
            ' Copy the value and then blank the source.
            Range("E" & row).Value = Range("H" & row).Value
            Range("H" & row).Value = ""
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Which avoiding using row as a variable name and a few other tidies could be:

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub SetValues()
    Dim currentRow As Long
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("102Tk")  'taking note of the comments and using worksheet collection to avoid Chart sheets
        For currentRow = 17 To 1000
            ' Check if "save" appears in the value anywhere.
            If Not IsNumeric(.Range("H" & currentRow)) Then
                ' Copy the value and then blank the source.
                .Range("E" & currentRow) = .Range("H" & currentRow)
                .Range("H" & currentRow) = vbNullString
            End If
        Next currentRow
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Your code works but it copies all the values. I just need text values to be transferred not numbers. Do you know anyway I can change that?

Comment: This is giving a different error message on the line "If Not IsNumeric(.Range("H" & i)) Then" The error message is "Application-defined or object-defined error"

Comment: on which line is the error? If the first time worked so should the second , I think, as I have only changed the test.

Comment: If Not IsNumeric(.Range("H" & currentRow)) Then

Comment: That doesn't seem possible as currentRow starts at 17 so is greater than 0 and H17:H1000 exists as a valid range. And IsNumeric is a standard test. What is your Excel subscription and version and OS?

Comment: @ManishShiwlani Did you copy the whole code, or just that one section - you'll get that error if you still have `Dim row as Long` instead of `Dim currentRow as Long`

Comment: @QHarr One way that line *could* error is if `ThisWorkbook.Sheets("102Tk")` was a Chartsheet instead of a Worksheet - but that would be `Run-time error '438': Object doesn't support this proerty or method` instead

Comment: @Chronocidal yes. and this is why you should retrieve worksheets through the `Worksheets` collection. And if the sheet exists at compile-time, then you should be using its `CodeName` instead - there's already a project-scope `Worksheet` object variable for every worksheet that exists at compile-time, right there waiting to be used. No need to dereference these sheets every time.